# How to prevent duplicate entries?

Tags: android

I am beginner android developer.I am writing app witch write calls(incomming,outgoing,missed) to Android Calendar with some useful informations about call.Now i am trying to prevent from duplicate entries.For example if i run this app 2x and the calendar will be filled with duplicate entries.Has anybody got some great idea how to do it?I thought about this, i save date of last call witch is written to the calendar and then it will continue from this date.
Sorry for my English.

Comment: How do you define duplicate. ? Based on content??

Comment: Yes, based on content.(For example same date,same content, atd. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would check to see if there exists a calendar entry with the same start/end time before you write anything to the calendar. That would make sure that the same entry is never written twice, even if the app is uninstalled/reinstalled.

Comment: Yes,it crossed my mind too and that is better then save current date.Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You have the right idea.  After the program is run, save the current date (in `long` form) as a [SharedProperty](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref).  When you load up the application next time, grab the last run date and then ignore every missed call before that date.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to create a separate, private SQLite database that stores what you've inserted into the calendar and that utilizes SQL's `unique` attribute to determine if you should insert a new item into the calendar based on whether it's already been inserted.

Comment: Great idea, but first I must read something about it.I never done it.